# Issue In Compiling/Deploying Java Adapter in MFP 7.1 using ANT

Tags: java, ant, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have the following java version which is a must to be used in my project:

```
Hussams-MacBook-Pro:buildscripts SamEddin$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_112-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-ea-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.112-b04, mixed mode)
```

I'm using this ant to compile my java adapter which is giving a success result:

```
    <taskdef resource="com/worklight/ant/defaults.properties">
        <classpath>
          <pathelement location="${WL_PATH}/worklight-ant-builder.jar"/>
        </classpath>
      </taskdef>

      <path id="server-classpath">
                <fileset dir="${WL_PATH}" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar" />
                <fileset dir="${WL_PATH}" includes="**/*.jar" />
                <fileset dir="${basedir}/source/${project.name}/adapters/GRSValidationAdapter/lib" includes="**/*.jar"/>

      </path>

 <javac
      srcdir="${basedir}\source\${project.name}\adapters\GRSValidationAdapter\src\ca\manulife\adapter"
      classpathref="server-classpath"
      destdir="${basedir}\AdapterClasses"
      verbose="true"
      includeantruntime="false"
      target="1.7"
    />

    <target name="build-adapter">

        <adapter-builder 
        destinationfolder="bin" 
        classpathref="server-classpath" 
        folder="${basedir}\source\${project.name}\adapters\GRSValidationAdapter"
            />
    </traget>
```

However, when I deploy the adapter to the server I'm getting the following error:

```
11:04:21:764 EDT] 000000b1 StatusMessage E StatusMessage createStatusMessage Preparation to deploy adapter 'GRSValidationAdapter' failed.
java.lang.Error: The adapter was built with a later version of Java than is used to run the server.
```

How can I force my ant to compile the Java classes in my adapter to use 1.7.

Notes:

I have both 1.7 and 1.8 is installed.

Server version: 7.1.0.00.20160401-2103

Comment: What application server did you use to install MFP?  WAS or Tomcat?  Then, what release of that application server?

Comment: I have used WAS Server

Comment: But what version of WAS?  Liberty, Base or ND and what level are you running?  I want to find out for you what version of Java that server supports.  If it supports 1.8, then the easiest solution for you may be to change the JDK that WAS uses.

Comment: Sorry, it is WAS ND version 8.5.5.9

Answer (score 0):

Set JAVA_HOME / PATH variables Under Linux Bash Profile
e.g: export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.7/bin/java --> of coz depend on your java path

Comment: I must use JAVA_HOME to 1.8, I can't switch it. I have other projects that running on same machine that needs this Java version. I need to force the ant to use 1.7 and not changing the whole Java_Home

Comment: "target" attribute on 1.7 version e.g <target name="compile">
  <javac target="1.7" srcdir=.../>
</target>

Comment: like add "target" to the "adapter-builder"?

Comment: I got this error : adapter-builder doesn't support the "target" attribute

Comment: <target name="compile">
  <javac target="1.7" srcdir=.../>
</target>

Comment: Add it in your Ant, mate! You use ant tool to compile it, right?

Comment: I already used javac, updated my question. How can I include the destdir from javac into my adapter-builder?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.5 or later, then you can use java 1.8 on your server.

Use [this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27005002) to see what version of Java ships with each version.  From there you can either upgrade your server, and/or change your WAS configuration to use your installed Java 1.8.

Make sense?

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense, I will get to my deployment team to see if we can update the JDK on WAS ND 8.5.5.9 to get this addressed.